# Masonry JS show items first on resize correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

**Problem: (All .items had absolute and top 0 => overlaps)**

**Its first show correcty when I resize the window.**

[image]

---

JavaScript (http://masonry.desandro.com/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var container = document.querySelector(\'#container\');
    var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
         itemSelector: \'.item\',
         columnWidth: container.querySelector(\'.grid-sizer\')
    });
 });
```

---

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item"><a><img/></a></div>
  <div class="item"><a><img/></a></div>
```

---

CSS:

```
#container {
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
}


#container:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#container .item img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #container .item,
    #container .grid-sizer {
        width: 49%;
        margin: 0.5% 0.5% 0 0.5%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) { 
    #container .item,
    #container .grid-sizer {
        width: 32.3%;
        margin: 0.5% 0.5% 0 0.5%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (min-width: 992px) {
    #container .item,
    #container .grid-sizer {
        width: 24%;
        margin: 0.5% 0.5% 0 0.5%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (min-width: 1200px) {
    #container .item,
    #container .grid-sizer {
        width: 11.5%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0.5% 0.5% 0 0.5%;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for articles about ResponsiveUI - that will give you much usefull info. "autoscaling" could be done with next code:

```
.wrapper img {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%
 height: 100%;
}
```